# Hello, is it possible to take user input of height and width from a form input and resize a picture in cm as output?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm trying to make a page that takes width and height from user input and resize the mtFuji picture after clicking on the submit form, please help me as i have to finish this for an assignment, thanks a lot!

```
<body>
<section>
    <div id="backgroundDiv">
        <div id="mainDiv">
               <div class="form-control">
               <form id="form" class="form" action="" method="GET">
                        <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="height">Height :</label>
                        <input type="number" name="height" placeholder="(9-12.cm)" id="height" />
                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                        <small>Error message</small>
                    </div>
                        <div class="form-control">
                        <label for="weight">Width :</label>
                        <input type="number" name="width" placeholder="(14-24.cm)" id="width" /></br>
                        <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                        <small>Error message</small>
                    </div>
                    <button id="next" value="next" onclick="goToPreview(), resizeImage();">submit</button>
                    <button id="print" value="print" onclick="window.print()">print</button>
            </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        <img id="mtFuji" src="resources/mt.fuji.jpg" alt="Mt.Fuji">
</section>
```

Comment: Its possible. Using Javascript (AJAX) might be the better way to go.

Comment: I think you can either manipulate the css style or the image width and height attributes: 
```<script>
function resizeImage(width, height){
   myimg = document.getElementById('mtFuji');
   myimg.style.height = height + "px";
   myimg.style.width =  width + "px";
}
</script>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.
And do consider checking the JS tutorial on [W3Schoools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp), in your spare time it's super amazing!

```js
const resizeImage = () => {
  const getId = (id) => document.getElementById(id);

  let height = getId('height').value ? `${getId('height').value}cm` : 'auto';
  let width = getId('width').value ? `${getId('width').value}cm` : 'auto';

  getId("mtFuji").style.height = height;
  getId("mtFuji").style.width = width;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <label for="height">Height :</label>
    <input type="number" name="height" placeholder="(9-12.cm)" id="height" />

    <label for="weight">Width :</label>
    <input type="number" name="width" placeholder="(14-24.cm)" id="width" />

    <button onclick="resizeImage();" type="button">Resize</button>
    <button onclick="window.print()">print</button>
  </form>

  <img id="mtFuji" src="https://blush-design.imgix.net/collections/40G09koP55fYh86yZDnX/b29c577b-5364-44c1-ae0b-b48c9e37676e.png?w=800&auto=format" alt="Mt.Fuji">
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
const imageToResize = document.getElementById('mtFuji');
const resizeImage = () => {
  imageToResize.setAttribute(
    'style',
    `width:${document.getElementById('width').value}; 
     height:${document.getElementById('height').value};`
  );
};
```

This works by selecting the image from the DOM, and when the function runs sets the value of the height and width to those in your inputs.